# Defining models with Mongoid for this database structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, mongodb, mongoid

Hey I'm trying to build a rails 3 app with Mongoid (for MongoDB).
What I'm now trying to do:

---

**Languages:**

*id (automatically created, right?)*

name (e.g. English)

code (e.g. en_US)

**Languages_Texts:**

*id (see above...)*

name (e.g. hello_world)

**Translations:**

*id (see above...)*

translation (e.g. Hello, world!)

---

I hope this database schema is understandable and not too bad. ;)

Now my problem is, that I don't know how to do this with a mongoid model in rails 3.

Anyone that could help me?

Thanks already!

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you need is three different models, language, languages_text, and translation. The models should look like this

```
class Language
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :code
end

class LanguagesText
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
end

class Translation
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :translation
end
```

This will put the data in different collections within the mongodb. Hope that helps